# Relational algebra - List the names of employees who do not work in the project 1

Tags: relational-algebra

I've the following tables:

```
Employee
|name|employee_cod|

Project
|name|project_cod|

Work
|employee_cod|project_cod|
```

So, how can I list the names of employees who not work, 
for example, in the project with project_cod = 1, with relational algebra?

The following not work:

```
π(employee.name(σ work.project_cod != 1 (Employee ∞ Work ∞ Project)
```

Because if I have the following data in work table:

```
| employee_cod | project_cod |
-------1--------------1-------
-------1--------------2-------
-------1--------------3-------
-------2--------------2-------
```

This `σ work.project_cod != 1` will result in:

```
| employee_cod | project_cod |
-------1--------------2-------
-------1--------------3-------
-------2--------------2-------
```

But the employee with code = 1 should not be returned, because it participates in project 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first find all the employees who **do** work on the project. Those who don't are produced by relational difference (minus) operator.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the tip Tegiri. 
The solution is:

```
π name (Employee) - ( π name (σ project_cod = 1 (Employee ∞ Work)))
```